# AWS SNS version different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using SNS and I noticed that depending of the region the "Mobile" dropdown in the left hand menu is displayed or not.

I'm using the "Text Messaging" option of that menu to test the SMS functionality (I know that I could do it with a Lambda calling SNS) that allows me to do quick test for numbers with different prefixes.

Does someone knows why that option is not displayed in some regions (e.g eu-west-2)? I suppose that is related to the SNS version deployed in that region, If so, how can I check the SNS version deployed in each region?

[image: sns region comparation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS deploys features mostly on region-by-region basis.

As per the SNS feature you need, it is available on certain regions only as stated in the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html).